How to create a jQuery event without binding it to an element and how to bind it later?
I'm trying to create and store a jQuery event without binding it to an element.
I tried to do this:
var e = jQuery.Event("click", function() { 
   console.log("Click event triggered"); 
});

but I don't know how can I bind it to a jQuery element later.
I also tried to create an event using jQuery.fn.on, but again I didn't know, how could I bind it to a desired element later.
I basically only want to create an event containing information about event type and a callback function, without needing to define an element at the moment of creating it.
How can I achieve such a result?

What you actually want to create is an event handling function (and not an event) that will be bound to an event at a later stage.
You can do this like you would create a "normal" function. This function should accept the current event object as its argument and you can use the this keyword in it to refer to the DOM element that will have triggered the event.
function fn1(ev){
  console.log(`A ${this.tagName} element was ${ev.type}ed.`)
}

Then, either as part of a delegated or direct event-assignment, you could do
$("#myButton").on("click",fn1)

to put the function into action by binding it to the "click" event of the element with id "myButton".
The delegated event binding could look like this;
$("body").on("click",".myButton",fn1)

This would bind the event handler to any currently existing or future DOM element with the class "myButton" inside the body element.

Thank you, I think I understand it now. That would indeed be some way to achieve that result. I still wonder however, if in jQuery it would be possible to do these things separately, as with Event object, creating it as with const e = document.createEvent("Event");, specifying its type then and dispatching it with elem.dispatchEvent(e); later

I think what I wished for was, that jQuery.fn.on.bind($("body"), "click", "#elem", function(e) { console.log("Click event triggered")})() would return an event object e, that could normally be achieved from a callback function function(e) {} with information, that I could use to turn it on and off later. It seems not to work like that, however, and returns undefined, unfortunately

Well, yes, that might be possible. Alternatively you could of course also just call the (named) function itself with a suitable event object as the first parameter.
